# Using pandas to summarize and plot data

Tags: python, pandas

I will like to use pandas to summarize or visualize some useful summary from my data to highlight how suppliers deviate from the date order was due for supply. Here's a snippet of my data frame:

```
Supplier    TimeDiff (days)
A   3 days
B   4 days
B   12 days
A   0 days
C   1 days
B   2 days
D   3 days
E   5 days
E   7 days
```

"Supplier" column contain the supplier codes and "TimeDiff" column contain time difference (date range obtained by deducting "order due date" from "order received date").

Does anyone know how best I can summarise this data? Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you want to learn from this data? You can for example get average "TimeDiff" for each supplier like this: `data.groupby('Supplier').mean()['TimeDiff']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with calculating the mean TimeDiff by supplier:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['A', '3 days'], ['B', '4 days'], ['B', '12 days'], ['A', '0 days']], columns=['Supplier', 'TimeDiff'])
df['TimeDiff'] = df['TimeDiff'].str.extract(r'(\d+)').astype(int)
print df.groupby('Supplier').mean()

          TimeDiff
Supplier          
A              1.5
B              8.0

res.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you guys for these solutions. I wonder if its possible to compute a bar chart directly.